# Problems with if/elif - Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Ok, coming from here:
[Read only 4 first letters of .txt file - Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841504/read-only-4-first-letters-of-txt-file-python3)
This is my second question (sorry for the noob questions..).
I succeed reading the platform in 4 letters, now what I want is that if platform = mt81 or mt67 continue and if not exit.
For that I used:

```
if platform == "mt81" or "mt67":
       continue
elif platform != "mt81" or != "mt67":
       wait = input("Incompatible CPU! BYE!")
       break
```

If I execute my python file there's no errors but when I click on the option that reads platform, nothing happens and it returns to menu but if I remove that if/elif the tool is working but without platform detect..

I tried:

```
if "mt81" in platform or "mt67" in platform:
       continue
elif "mt81" not in platform or "mt67" not in platform:
       wait = input("Incompatible CPU! BYE!")
       break
```

But same result...

Any ideas of what I can do?
Thanks again!

EDIT
FULL CODE:

```
import os
import subprocess

#set null variables
supported = ['mt81', 'mt67']

def menu():
        """
        Fucntion to clean
        """
        os.system('clear')
        print("\t Big thanks to diplomatic")
        print("\t1 - Root the Device")
        print("\t2 - Spawn Root Shell")
        print("\t3 - Exit")

while True:
        #show menu
        menu()

        #user sets option
        option = input("Select an option >> ")

        if option=="1":
             print("Detecting device information....")
             print("--------------------------------------")
             subprocess.call("adb shell getprop ro.boot.veritymode > verity.txt",shell=True)
             with open('verity.txt') as myfile:
               verity = myfile.read()
             subprocess.call("adb shell getprop debug.mtklog.netlog.Running > mtk.txt",shell=True)
             with open('mtk.txt') as myfile:
               mtk = myfile.read()
             subprocess.call("adb shell getprop ro.product.model > device.txt",shell=True)
             with open('device.txt') as myfile:
               device = myfile.read()
             subprocess.call("adb shell getprop ro.hardware > platform.txt",shell=True)
             with open('platform.txt', 'r') as myfile:
               platform = myfile.read(4)
             subprocess.call("adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi > arch.txt",shell=True)
             with open('arch.txt') as myfile:
               arch = myfile.read()
             subprocess.call("adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release > android.txt",shell=True)
             with open('android.txt') as myfile:
               android = myfile.read()
             print("Device: " + device)
             print("ARCH: " + arch)
             print("Platform: " + platform)
             print("Android: " + android)
             print("--------------------------------------")
             if platform == "mt81" or "mt67":
               continue
             elif platform != "mt81" or != "mt67":
               wait = input("Incompatible CPU! BYE!")
               break
             if "enforcing" in verity:
                 print("Sorry! Your device seems to have DM-Verity, this method will not work. Exiting...")
                 break
             elif " " in verity:
                 continue
             # ty t0x1cSH
             if "arm64-v8a" in arch:
                print("--------------------------------------")
                print("Detected arm64 arch.. Pushing arm64 mtk-su & files")
                subprocess.call("adb push arm64/mtk-su arm64/root.sh arm64/su arm64/supolicy arm64/libsupol.so /data/local/tmp",shell=True)
                print("--------------------------------------")
                print("Pushed files succsefully!")
                print("Rooting the device...")
                subprocess.call("adb install files/SuperSU.apk",shell=True)
                subprocess.call("adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/mtk-su",shell=True)
                subprocess.call("adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/root.sh",shell=True)
                subprocess.call('adb shell /data/local/tmp/mtk-su -c "/data/local/tmp/root.sh"',shell=True)
                wait = input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")
                os.system('clear')
             # ty t0x1cSH
             elif "armeabi-v7a" in arch:
                print("Detected armv7 arch.. Pushing armv7 mtk-su & files")
                subprocess.call("adb push arm/mtk-su arm/root.sh arm/su arm/supolicy arm/libsupol.so /data/local/tmp",shell=True)
                print("--------------------------------------")
                print("Pushed files succsefully!")
                print("Rooting the device...")
                subprocess.call("adb install files/SuperSU.apk",shell=True)
                subprocess.call("adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/mtk-su",shell=True)
                subprocess.call("adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/root.sh",shell=True)
                subprocess.call('adb shell /data/local/tmp/mtk-su -c "/data/local/tmp/root.sh"',shell=True)



        elif option=="2":
               print("ROOT SHELL SPAWNER")
               subprocess.call("adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi > arch.txt",shell=True)
               with open('arch.txt') as myfile:
                  arch = myfile.read()
               print("Spawning Root Shell... \n For exit type 'exit' two times or Control+C for terminate the script")
               # ty again t0x1cSH :)
               if "arm64-v8a" in arch:
                   subprocess.call("adb push arm64/mtk-su /data/local/tmp",shell=True)
                   subprocess.call("adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/mtk-su",shell=True)
                   subprocess.call("adb shell /data/local/tmp/mtk-su",shell=True)
                   wait = input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")
                   os.system('clear')
               elif "armeabi-v7a" in arch:
               # ty again again XD
                   subprocess.call("adb push arm/mtk-su /data/local/tmp",shell=True)
                   subprocess.call("adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/mtk-su",shell=True)
                   subprocess.call("adb shell /data/local/tmp/mtk-su",shell=True)
                   wait = input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")
                   os.system('clear')

        elif option=="3":
               break

        else:
               print("")
               input("Incorrect option...\nPress any key to continue..")
```

Comment: To use elif you have to use an else statement. But either way it is better to change your first if to have the break statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you want to pass the code not continue, so try to change continue to pass. `continue` starts the next loop at the beginning and `pass` just pass to the next code.

```
if platform in ('mt81', 'mt67'):
// if platform in set(supported):
    pass
else:
    wait = input("Incompatible CPU! BYE!")
    break
```

The commented `if` sentence is for using the defined list `supported` if you wish.

Comment: Thanks but same result.
Also I'm in a while loop, IDK if this affects. And I need to add : after else cause it was giving me syntax error.

EDIT: switching to if ('mt81', 'mt67') in platform gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mtk-su_linux.py", line 53, in <module>
    if ('mt81', 'mt67') in platform:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Comment: Please try again with `pass` not `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

How does this value for `platform` look in the file?

I think `platform` is the variable whose value you have to compare. So taking `platform` to be a string you can check if `platform` starts with the two strings you have: `'mt81'` and `'mt67'`. 
What you can do is:

```
if platform.startswith('mt81') or  platform.startswith('mt67'):
    continue;
else:
    print("Incompatible platform.\n")
```

What you are doing is comparing if `platform` is same as 'mt81', which may not be an exact match all the time given that there may space or special character in it. So better use the string function `startswith`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
Platform is the first 4 letters from a .txt file.
I've tried what you suggested but still the same, return to menu with no output.